# Как массово SQL-запросом заменить теги div оформленные стилями под h2 на реальные теги h2

Tags: mysql, sql, битрикс

Столкнулся с задачей заменить html тег `<div>`, оформленный стилями под `<h2> <div class="title-section">` на реальный `<h2>`. Так как страниц очень много, хотелось бы это сделать массово SQL-запросом. Я написал запрос

```
UPDATE `b_iblock_element`
SET `DETAIL_TEXT` = REPLACE(`DETAIL_TEXT`, '<div class="title-section">', '<h2 class="title-section">') WHERE `DETAIL_TEXT`
LIKE '%<div class="title-section">%';
```

Но это запрос изменит только `<div class="title-section">` на `<h2 class="title-section">`, а `</div>` на `</h2>` не изменится. То есть `<div class="title-section">Тестовый заголовок</div>` изменится на `<h2 class="title-section">Тестовый заголовок</div>`

Comment: Очень плохое решение хранить html в базе. Но всё же вы не пробовали сделать тоже самое, только в `REPLACE` указать `</div>` поменять на `</h2>`?))

Comment: На странице много блоков div поэтому если так сделать запрос и их зацепит

Comment: Тогда скриптик набросать, который получит записи, исправит их и вставит обратно, вряд ли тут одним sql можно обойтись

Comment: Понял Спасибо)!